# Get ACF taxonomy term and sub-term lists ACF blocks

Tags: taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, block-editor

I want to get list of parents and child terms from ACF field type Taxonomy. This things need to display as ACF blocks. i have tried many things to done this stuffs but but it's not working for me.
Screenshots:
Frontend:
https://shorturl.at/sHK02
Backend:
https://shorturl.at/ESV06
ACF Field:
https://shorturl.at/lntI7

```
 <div class="filter">
                        <small class="filter-title">Categories</small>
                        <div class="filter--select">
                            <div class="filter--select-active"><span class="filter--select-active-text">All</span></div>
                            <div class="filter--select-options">
                                <div class="filter--accordion">
                                    <div class="filter--accordion-title">
                                        <h5>Blog</h5>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <input id="blog" type="checkbox" value="filter0">
                                            <label for="blog"></label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="filter--accordion-body">
                                        <li>
                                            <p>Career advancement</p>
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <input id="careerAdvancement" type="checkbox" value="filter1">
                                                <label for="careerAdvancement"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <p>Leadership</p>
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <input id="leadership" type="checkbox" value="filter2">
                                                <label for="leadership"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <p>Technical skills</p>
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <input id="technicalSkills" type="checkbox" value="filter3">
                                                <label for="technicalSkills"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <p>Thought leadership</p>
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <input id="thoughtLeadership" type="checkbox" value="filter4">
                                                <label for="thoughtLeadership"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <p>Current events</p>
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <input id="currentEvents" type="checkbox" value="filter5">
                                                <label for="currentEvents"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                         
                              
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-reset" id="clear-filters">Reset filter</div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked with ACF?  Third-Party plugins are off topic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.